# why is Vuejs disabling the ability of a media query to add and remove component

Tags: vue.js

Given i have this

```
//mycompoent.js

Vue.component('main-nav',{
    template:`
     <div id="main-nav">
     </div>
    `
}); 

Vue.component('menu-nav',{
    template:`
     <div id="menu-nav">
     </div>
    `
});

new Vue({
}).$mount("#nav-app");
```

Then in my CSS I have the following

```
//style.css

#menu-nav{display:none;}

@media (max-width:840px){
   #main-nav{display:none;}
   #menu-nav{display:block;}
}

//index.html

<div id="nav-app">
    <main-nav />
    <menu-nav />
</div>
```

When I resize the browser less than 840px the menu-nav component never appears; I don't know what I have done wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're testing this directly in the browser (without a compile step), you can't use the self-closing form `<main-nav />` for components. Try the following:

`<div id="nav-app">
    <main-nav></main-nav>
    <menu-nav></menu-nav>
</div>`